# Error: Parameter token or opts.auth is required

Tags: github, github-actions

I have already specified my PAT with all the necessary accees. Still it is throwing error. Any suggestion would help me. Here is my workflow.

```
release:
   needs: build-dev
   runs-on: windows-latest
   steps:
      - name: Create release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        with:
          token:  ${{ secrets.RELEASE_TOKEN }}
          tag_name: ${{ needs.build-dev.outputs.version }}
          release_name: Release ${{ needs.build-dev.outputs.version }}
          prerelease: false
```

Comment: Did you observe [the action](https://github.com/actions/create-release) wasn't maintained anymore, had newest versions, and was suggesting other alternatives in the readme file? It also suggest to inform a token is by using an **env variable** at the step level: `env: GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` (could be a PAT secret as well).

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd , thanks for helping out, I have red and implemented the same env: GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} and GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_PAT}} . where in these both variable I stored the PAT value but still getting the same error. Do I need to upgrade the version ?

Comment: Hey @GuiFalourd But I have the enterprise subscription where in my organization i am running the pipeline. Is there any other token do i need to pass , i dont think so because PAT with proper acces can call the api , right ?

Comment: `Do I need to upgrade the version ?`: The problem here is that you can't use the `GITHUB_` prefix to set a secret (it's in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets)). Try using directly the secret like this: `env: GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}`

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd , Thanks for your suggestion. The error was in my workflow task where I was using different agent , where I missed the environment when I have specified the secrets into dev environment for which it was not able to find the variable in the global variable section.